# For which values of $n$ does $1 + 2 + \cdots + n$ divide $n!\ \ \ $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem is to find all values of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $$1 + 2 + \cdots + n \vert n!$$

Maybe writing $1 + 2 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ might help, but I don't have a clue on how to proceed.

Here some values of n for which $1 + 2 + \cdots + n$ does not divide $n!$:
$$2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 16, 18, 22, 28, 30, 36, 40, 42, 46, 52, 58, 60, 66, 70, 72, 78, 82, 88, 96$$

Thanks!

Comment: See [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem).

Comment: No need of Wilson's theorem here. It is pure divisibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: add $1$ to each of the numbers in your list.

> If $n+1$ is prime, then $(n+1)n/2$ won't divide $n!$.  Otherwise, it can be written as the product of primes less than $n$ and will divide $n!$